# Query this=$value AND (this =$value1 OR $value2)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

Probably a similar topic on the web, but it was a difficult search.
I got thousand of results, but none with the exact problem i have.

So im working in Yii, and i need a query to give me the following.

One column must be equal to $firsvariable and another column must be equal to $seconvariable OR $thirdvariable. The second column has only 3 options in a enum.

Now, i've tried several different approches, and tried to read up on CDbCriteria Class reference, but no luck so far.

Ive tried

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = "column1=".$firstvariable;
$criteria->addCondition('column2!= 2', 'AND');
```

and

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = "column1=".$firstvariable;
$criteria->addCondition('(column2 = 0 OR column2 = 1)', 'AND');
```

And several more.

Comment: Do you really mean two *rows*, or two *columns*?

Comment: What's wrong with this? $criteria->addCondition('(column2 ='. $seconvariable .'OR column2 ='.$thirdvariable.')', 'AND');

Comment: Wish i knew :) It just does not return any rows. I even ran - SELECT * FROM table WHERE (`column1` = 2) AND ((`column2` = 0) OR (`column2` = 2)) - handwritten in phpMyAdmin without results. And i know I have rows that meet those criterias. So the sql-syntax must be wrong..

Comment: Are these values the actual enum values or the enum position? If they are the values, they need to be strings.

Comment: It sounds like your problem is purely with the sql query.  Could you add a few rows from your table to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->addCondition('column1 = value1');
    $criteria->addCondition('column2 = value2 OR column2 = value3');
```

It should work.